# Google maps infoWindow tip placement issues

Tags: google-maps, position, infowindow

I have a problem displaying `infoWindows` correctly on my Google map. For some reason my `infoWindows` have started to show the tip (pointing to the marker) incorrectly. Somehow they get displaced.

I've tried changing the `pixelOffset` property on the `infoWindow` options, but this changes nothing.

[image]

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered, that I had to set CSS border to 0px in the map-canvas element. That solved my problem:

```
#map-canvas{
   border:0px;
}
```